# Can you actually print envelopes in Quicken 2014 Deluxe Release R 7 (23.1.7.6) on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: quicken

I went to print off an envelope today in Quicken 2014 Deluxe Release R 7 (23.1.7.6) and it only printed my return address; it doesn't print the selected payee.  I've read on the Intuit community forums that this is something they never get around to fixing; is this true?  Because Quicken 2014 Deluxe costs enough that I would hope you could actually print from it!!!!

[image: The Quicken 2014 Address Book Feature]

See above with one of the payees selected, click `Print->Envelopes`...

[image: Oh look the Print Envelope screen]
Wouldn't you think that in the resulting `Print Envelope` screen, if you selected `Print selected contacts`, that it would, oh I don't know...PRINT THE ATLANTIC BROADBAND CONTACT ON THE ENVELOPE??!!?  REALLY?  Well let's see what happens...

[image: Oh look, it printed just the return address!]

It only prints the return address.

It's in `Tools->Address Book`, select an address, shove an envelope in your printer and click print.  If you're lucky you'll get to see your own address printed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is strictly a technical question about software.

Comment: Well then transfer it to another stackexchange where it's relevant.

Comment: Instead of being about as helpful as Intuits customer service!

Comment: Be nice. I have no power to do that; I'm just a regular user. You can repost at superuser.com. Computer software questions of a strictly technical nature belong there.

Comment: Oh okay sorry man...I didn't know you weren't a big bad moderator, but I now see that you don't have a black diamond by your name.

Comment: Yup, I gave up my mod superpowers last year, and there have been moderator elections since. Check out our [meta site](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com) where you'll see we discuss such things, including issues like [Do technical questions about tools belong?](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-technical-questions-about-tools-belong). You are welcome to express an opinion on the matter there.

Answer (score 1):

Quicken was originally designed to print *checks* with addresses on them, which could be used with window envelopes for mailing. It sounds like they're still assuming you'll use it that way, which means the envelopes would only need the return address.

(I never used it that way -- always hand-wrote checks AND envelopes, and just used Quicken as a ledger.)

Comment: Look at the screenshots above and tell me this isn't how it's supposed to work.

Comment: What it's supposed to do in theory, and what the customers are actually using it for, are sometimes quite different, and the developers' priority is going to be to fix the things that people are demanding be fixed. If this annoys you, contact Intuit and tell them you need it; if enough people do so, it'll get done.

Comment: In that case here's my ticket, upvote it if you too are annoyed: https://qlc.intuit.com/questions/995863-can-you-actually-print-envelopes-in-quicken-2014-deluxe-release-r-7-23-1-7-6-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: Well if you Upgrade to Quicken 2015 it appears to work.